# How do I make a property that updates itself automatically based on some other value(s)?

Tags: javascript, properties

Suppose I have an object like this with some arbitrary values...

```
let object = {
  value: 5,
  min: 1,
  max: 100,
  valid: true
}
```

How could I make it so that the `valid` property updates automatically if the `value` property is not within the range? I know I could have made a `getter` in the object like this...

```
get valid() {
  if (this.value > this.max || this.value < this.min) {
    return false
  else {
    return true
  }
}
```

...but this only updates `valid` when it is **accessed.** I need `valid` to always be up to date based on the other values of the object.

It's often that I eventually realize that my entire way of thinking about a problem was wrong. Is this one of those cases? For example, I know that if I use `setter` functions for updating all three of the other objects I could use them to keep `valid` up to date, but that seems like the wrong approach.

What should I do?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's not up to date when it's *not* being accessed?

Comment: Both the approaches you suggested seem good to me. There's no need for a property to be up-to-date when it's not accessed. The setter approach is flawless. Why not use it? You would actually need only one setter for the ```value``` property

Comment: The only reason I can think of is if you parse the object, serialize it, view it in the log or something along those lines, the value needs to be up-to-date. If that's the case then I think going about it with setters like you suggested is the best solution. Otherwise, I don't see why you can't solve this in the getter as you also suggested.

Comment: One setter is not enough. If the `min` or `max` properties were changed causing the `value` to be out of range, then the `valid` property would not be true. The reason why I need to do things this way is because I have an external library watching the value of the `valid` property and doing its thing based on the value. Therefore, it is up to my object to ensure that the `valid` property is always correct.

Comment: Also you can maybe add a function `updateObj()` that will update the property accordingly. Then make setters for `value`, `min`, and `max` that call `updateObj()` after changing their values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I can think of doing it without getters.
It updates the value of `valid` every time the other properties are updated.

```js
var obj = {
  val: 5,
  minimum: 1,
  maximum: 100,
  valid: true,
  set value(v) {
    this.val = v;
    this.updateValid();
  },
  set min(m) {
    this.minimum = m;
    this.updateValid();
  },
  set max(m) {
    this.maximum = m;
    this.updateValid();
  },
  updateValid : function() {
    this.valid = (this.val >= this.minimum && this.val <= this.maximum)
  }
}
obj.value = -1;
console.log(obj);
```